# Trapezoid mesh, contour and surfacing from multiple 3d lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, contour, geometry-surface

I have 4 points of a trapezoid and dZ for my third axes. The data is in three sets:

[image: data plot]

I would like to make a contour map of this from the minimum dz point and do it in levels of 0.1. I would also like to make a smooth surface from my three lines.

How can I do this?

Comment: the three lines are the same lines from the data set, figure 2 shows X,Y view, i can easily find the four conrner points for the trapezoid from the blue and green line. the problem however is creating a mesh, and usign the dZ data and building a contour from it

Comment: It'd be helpful if you give us the code you have already tried, or that produced these plots.

Comment: the code for the plot is jsut
  plot3(X1,Y1,dZ1,'-r')
and repeat for X2 and X3